# Using multiline & editable to make placeholder go above input text

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

In react-native I know that you can use the multiline and editable props inside TextInput. Currently I'm trying to make it so that when a user enters their username into the textbox, the placeholder text (Enter username) appears above the input text inside the textbox. When I use multiline it gets the result that I want, however even if I use autoFocus somehow to get the user to start typing inside the newly generated line, they can still edit the old text input line that got moved above. I was thinking that I could use the editable prop somehow to make it immutable. So if anyone has a way to do this with a combination of autoFocus, multiline, and editable in react-native please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextInput
    style={{
      height: 60,
      borderColor: 'gray',
      borderWidth: 1,
      fontSize: 16,
      padding: 10,
    }}
    multiline
    editable={false} // Set editable to false
    autoFocus={true}
    placeholder="Enter username"
    defaultValue={username} // Use defaultValue to set the initial value
    onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
  />
```

the multiline prop allows the TextInput to display multiple lines of text. editable={false} makes the TextInput read-only, preventing the user from editing the text manually. autoFocus={true} ensures that the TextInput is focused when the component is rendered. The defaultValue prop is used to set the initial value of the TextInput, which is controlled by the username state variable.

With these props set up, the placeholder text "Enter username" will appear above the input text inside the textbox. The user won't be able to edit the text manually, ensuring the immutability you desire. The defaultValue prop also enables you to capture the input text in the username state variable for further processing if needed.